# Interface Extension - Base Class or Extension Method

Tags: c#

I read about using extension methods to add methods to the interface, however I was also thinking on why not to have a base class derived from the interface containing virtual methods (that of course if you have flexibility to design from the start). Using base class adds to the flexibility of overriding as well, if need be.

Comment: A base class isn't more flexible. You're basically forcing every implementation of the interface to extend this base class instead of either choosing its own base class, or not having one at all.

Comment: That doesn't work in the many situations where you can't change the classes... Now, what is your actual *question*?

Answer (score 3):

Both have different advantages.

Base class:

- You can store *state* in private fields.
- The methods can be overridden in the subclasses, if necessary.
- The implementation is in one place rather than scattered over (potentially) many extension method classes.

Extension method:

- Does not require your interface implementers to inherit from a given base class. Since C# does not support multiple inheritance, this can be an important issue.
- Does not require access to the source code of the class.